# How to update input value using ref in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have one input which i want to update using ref only(not using setState).
constructor(props) {
super(props);

```
    this.Increase = this.Increase.bind(this)
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        inputVal: -1
    };
}

<div>
<input type="number" ref={textInput} placeholder="count"/>
<span onClick={this.Increase}>Increase
</span>
</div>
```

and i have one function where i want to use to increase input value

```
Increase(event){
//access ref here and update input value using ref
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just like changing a mere normal field value.
You could just do :

```
Increase(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.textInput.current.value += 1;
}
```

Comment: i want to use ref

Comment: You're actually using ref (the one you created). Or are you talking about the hook??

Answer (score 1):

The first step to fix this problem is to pass the ref properly:

```
<div>
    <input type="number" ref={this.textInput} placeholder="count"/>
    <span onClick={this.Increase}>Increase</span>
</div>
```

then you should add this `Increase` function:

```
Increase(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.textInput.current.value = "2" //everything you want;
}
```

Comment: also you can visit this https://jsfiddle.net/9bgxr372/12/